# R - odd behavior of simple call to `sample()`

Tags: r

Why does this work (`char`):

```
sample(c("5516"), size=1, replace=F, prob=c(1))

> [1] "5516"
```

But not this (`int`):

```
sample(c(5516), size=1, replace=F, prob=c(1))

> Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

I can avoid sampling for this trivial case with `length()` but am curious why `sample` is failing under this condition?

Thank you.

Comment: `?sample`, start reading at the very start of "Details".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/sample) which describes this (intended) behavior:

> Details
>
> **If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x.** Note that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour when x is of varying length in calls such as sample(x). See the examples.